# Go to comment form on button/link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button/link like this

```
<a href='#' id='button-element'><span class='fa fa-comment' ></span></a>
```

Comment form like this

```
<form method="POST" id="comment_form">
     ....
     <textarea name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
</form>
```

And I've added this JS so when I click on the button should go, focus and put border around the comment_content textarea.

```
    var $code = $('#comment_content');
    $('#button-element').on('mousedown', function () {
        $(this).data('inputFocused', $code.is(":focus"));
    }).click(function () {
        if ($(this).data('inputFocused')) {
            $code.blur();
        } else {
            $code.focus();
        }
    });
```

The problem is that I have multiple items with multiple comment buttons and the above solution works only when I click on the first item. If I click on other button it doesn't work.

Bellow is how it is working currently. What can be the problem?

```js
    var $code = $('#comment_content');
  $('#button-element').on('mousedown', function () {
   $(this).data('inputFocused', $code.is(":focus"));
  }).click(function () {
   if ($(this).data('inputFocused')) {
    $code.blur();
   } else {
    $code.focus();
   }
  });
```

```css
#comment_content:focus, #comment_content:active { 
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='#' id='button-element'><span class='fa fa-comment' ></span>Button 1</a>
<a href='#' id='button-element'><span class='fa fa-comment' ></span>Button 2</a>
<a href='#' id='button-element'><span class='fa fa-comment' ></span>Button 3</a>
<a href='#' id='button-element'><span class='fa fa-comment' ></span>Button 4</a>



<form method="POST" id="comment_form">

    <textarea name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: `id` must be unique in the document. You have to define different id for each `<a>` tag

Comment: You're re-using `id`s in your HTML, which is invalid.  When you *identify* an element as `#button-element`, how is the browser to know which one you mean?  Did you mean instead to use `class` values?  Did you mean to use unique `id` values?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` must be unique in the document. You may use `class` instead.

```js
var $code = $('#comment_content');
  $('.button-element').on('mousedown', function () {
   $(this).data('inputFocused', $code.is(":focus"));
  }).click(function () {
   if ($(this).data('inputFocused')) {
    $code.blur();
   } else {
    $code.focus();
   }
  });
```

```css
#comment_content:focus, #comment_content:active { 
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='#' class='button-element'><span class='fa fa-comment' ></span>Button 1</a>
<a href='#' class='button-element'><span class='fa fa-comment' ></span>Button 2</a>
<a href='#' class='button-element'><span class='fa fa-comment' ></span>Button 3</a>
<a href='#' class='button-element'><span class='fa fa-comment' ></span>Button 4</a>



<form method="POST" id="comment_form">

    <textarea name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh, that was easy. I didn't tough about it. Thanks a lot!